# Easyphp 5.3.5.0 and Ajax: maybe json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, easyphp

I'm using Easyphp 5.3.5.0 on my pc to bulid some Ajax simple dynamic operations.

I would to refresh a list on click to "add item" button, so the button have an event on click.

The first javascript page do this in the click event:

```
$.post("operation/insert.php", { type : "cliente", name : nome, surname : cognome ,  description : descrizione, day : giornoNascita, month : meseNascita, year : annoNascita }, function(data){  
alert("HELLO!");
},'json');
```

In the Php page, "operation/insert.php", after preliminar checks on the variables I run this code:

```
$q_add_client = mysql_query($query);

    $return = array(
        id => mysql_insert_id(),
        response => 0
    );

    echo json_encode($return);
```

I'm sure that the query is executed, because I can see the new item in my database. But, at the end, i don't see my alert("HELLO!"), so i think that there's a problem with json_encode function and his parameters. It don't execute my callback function in Javascript module, at row $.post(...).

Can anyone help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're telling $.post to expect 'json' from the server, and
whenever you send json to the output, you should set correct content-type
first:

```
$q_add_client = mysql_query($query);

$return = array(
    'id' => mysql_insert_id(),
    'response' => 0
);

header("content-type: application/json");

echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: i have already in top of my php file the code 

header("Content-Type:application/json");

it's curious, it run in some other my projects!

Comment: And if you directly access: operation/insert.php, do you get the right output?

Comment: Ive noticed missing quotes in your $return array (fixed those for the answer), so maybe some syntax error is the problem?

Comment: Great! This is the problem, but i don't know why it run in other my applications, without quotes... big mystery
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax using jQuery.ajax method

```
$.ajax({
                url:'operation/insert.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                 type : "cliente", name : nome, surname : cognome ,  description : descrizione, day : giornoNascita, month : meseNascita, year : annoNascita
                },
                success:function(data){
                    alert('HELLO');
                }
      })
```

and if you got an error like as your comment below

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead
```

write this code in your page

```
if (!event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault = function() {
        event.returnValue = false; //ie
    };
}
```

Comment: open your console on the browser and tell me what is the result

Comment: my console says:

event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: i don't know why of this warning, but i'm using some functions with event onclick and onblur of items "input" and "textarea".

Comment: I'm talking about this functions:

function clickInput(nameItem, text) {
 var val = $("input[name='"+nameItem+"']").val();
 if(val == text) $("input[name='"+nameItem+"']").val("");
}

function onblurInput(nameItem, text) {
 var val = $("input[name='"+nameItem+"']").val();
 if(val == "") $("input[name='"+nameItem+"']").val(text);
}

Comment: The problem was the quotes in attributes of my json response, but i don't know why it run in other way, without quotes, in other applications.
Thank you for your support